# Is there a way to call Java from JavaScript in Webview?

Tags: javascript, android

Is there any way to call Java from JavaScript in Webview like this

> https://github.com/ochameau/NativeBridge

in Android?

Answer (score 4):

Use `addJavascriptInterface()` to add a Java object to the JavaScript environment of the WebView:

```
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new Locater(), "locater");
```

Your JavaScript can then reference methods on the fictitious object you injected:

```
<script language="javascript">
    function whereami() {
        var location=JSON.parse(locater.getLocation());

        document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML=location.lat;
        document.getElementById("lon").innerHTML=location.lon;
    }
</script>
```

where those methods are implemented on the Java object you used with `addJavascriptInterface()`.

[Here is a complete sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/WebKit/GeoWeb1) from which these bits of code were pulled that demonstrates this.